# Pulling the correct field into $this->Form->input in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp

I have a join model for `Users` and `Courses` called `Subscriptions`. In the subscription's add view, it [gives me a blank select](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5iL1V.jpg).

The correct field for the `User` would be `username`. And I'm sure it's calling something like `name` somewhere by mistake - I just have no idea where.

Can anyone help me? Thanks!

Comment: Nobody can answer this question until unless you will add some code in it. Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: "called Subscriptions" Please follow conventions. Models are singular. Also: You should always mention the exact cakephp version you are using.

Comment: @Anubhav - would you look at that. I got the answer I needed without pasting code.

Comment: @mark - sorry that was a typo. My model is singular.

Comment: @itamar I am really sorry...keep posting questions like this...

Comment: @Anubhav I can smell the sarcasm from here - but I agree - some more code would have helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you [set the displayField](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/model-attributes.html#displayfield) property on the User model?